Ошибка в пересылке поста с видео , фотографиями и текстом из телеграмм каналов
Вроде логику обработки поста написал правильно , но не может переслать пост в котором несколько фотографий с видео . Ошибка при обработке медиа:
HTTP Client says - ClientOSError: [Errno 2] Can not write request body for

Вот мой код обработки поста , полученного с помощью библиотеки telethon
router = Router()


media_groups = {}

async def handle_media(last_post, client, bot, TARGET_CHANNEL, text):
    """
    Обрабатывает медиафайлы (фото или документы) из последнего поста и отправляет их в целевой канал.
    """
    try:
        if not last_post.media:
            # Если нет медиа, просто отправляем текстовое сообщение
            await bot.send_message(chat_id=TARGET_CHANNEL, text=text)
            print("Текстовое сообщение отправлено.")
            return

        # Проверка наличия медиа
        media_group_builder = media_group.MediaGroupBuilder(caption=text)

        # Если это фото
        if isinstance(last_post.media, MessageMediaPhoto):
            file_name = "temp_photo.jpg"
            await client.download_media(last_post.media, file_name)
            if os.path.exists(file_name):
                media_group_builder.add_photo(media=FSInputFile(file_name))  # Добавляем фото в медиа-группу
                os.remove(file_name)  # Удаляем временный файл
            else:
                raise FileNotFoundError(f"Файл {file_name} не был найден!")

        # Если это видео (все видео в Telethon — это документы)
        elif isinstance(last_post.media, MessageMediaDocument):
            document = last_post.media.document
            if hasattr(document, 'video'):  # Проверяем, является ли документ видео
                file_name = "temp_video.mp4"
                await client.download_media(last_post.media, file_name)
                if os.path.exists(file_name):
                    media_group_builder.add_video(media=FSInputFile(file_name))  # Добавляем видео в медиа-группу
                    os.remove(file_name)  # Удаляем временный файл
                else:
                    raise FileNotFoundError(f"Файл {file_name} не был найден!")

        # Сформированная медиа-группа
        media_group_list = media_group_builder.build()

        # Проверка размера медиа-группы и отправка
        if len(media_group_list) > 10:
            chunk_size = 10
            for i in range(0, len(media_group_list), chunk_size):
                await bot.send_media_group(chat_id=TARGET_CHANNEL, media=media_group_list[i:i + chunk_size])
        else:
            await bot.send_media_group(chat_id=TARGET_CHANNEL, media=media_group_list)

        print("Медиа группа отправлена!")

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Ошибка при обработке медиа: {e}")
        await bot.send_message(chat_id=TARGET_CHANNEL, text=f"Ошибка при обработке медиа: {e}")

